# Bind to SelectedValue of ComboBox of string instantiated in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, data-binding

I have a literal ComboBox...

```
<ComboBox x:Name="DefaultAtt" SelectedValuePath=".">
    <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">Name</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Command</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>CommandParameter</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

and I want a binding to return the selected value.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=DefaultAtt, Path=SelectedValue}" />
```

But I get ToString version of the instance...

```
"System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: Name"
```

I tried `Path=SelectedItem.Content` but this returns `null`

How do I just select the value?

---

### Summary of Answers

This works without design or runtime errors, but is a bit verbose and heuristically dodgy

```
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=DefaultAtt, Path=Text}" />
```

This throws a binding error *'Text' property not found on 'object' ''ComboBoxItem'*

```
<ComboBox x:Name="DefaultAtt" SelectedValuePath="Text">
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=DefaultAtt, Path=SelectedValue}" />
```

This works without design or runtime errors

```
<ComboBox x:Name="DefaultAtt" SelectedValuePath="Content">
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=DefaultAtt, Path=SelectedValue}" />
```

This works without runtime errors, but VS2013 gives a warning squiggly (*Cannot resolve property 'Content' in data context of type 'object'*) and it is more verbose

```
<ComboBox x:Name="DefaultAtt" SelectedValuePath=".">
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=DefaultAtt, Path=SelectedValue.Content}" />
```

It also works without `SelectedValuePath="."`

This works but gives the same design time warning as above

```
<ComboBoxItem>Name</ComboBoxItem>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=DefaultAtt, Path=SelectedItem.Content}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either of these:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="DefaultAtt" SelectedValuePath="Content">
    <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">Name</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Command</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>CommandParameter</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=DefaultAtt, Path=SelectedValue}"/>
```

or

```
<ComboBox x:Name="DefaultAtt" SelectedValuePath=".">
    <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">Name</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Command</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>CommandParameter</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=DefaultAtt, Path=SelectedValue.Content}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<ComboBox x:Name="DefaultAtt" SelectedValuePath="Content">
```

The `SelectedValuePath` attribute defines the property of the list item that is to be used during binding - since your list contains items of type `ComboBoxItem`, you want to bind to their `Content` property!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=DefaultAtt, Path=Text}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually selectedvalue hold comboboxitem, So you can use below code to get desired output.

Comment: <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=DefaultAtt, Path=SelectedValue.Content}" />